# Modify batch to post full filename and extension

Tags: csv, batch-file

How can I change this batch so it will add filename.ext instead of just filename to the csv file?

```
for %%a in (*.csv) do call :addID "%%~Na" "%%a"

goto :EOF

:addId
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in (%2) do (
> #.csv echo %%b
goto :next
)
for /r %F in (*.pdf) do @echo %~nxF > %filename%
:next
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%b in (%2) do (

>> #.csv echo objects/%filename%.pdf,%filename%,%DATE%%%b
)
move #.csv %2
```

Comment: Your question unfortunately makes little sense. You are not setting `filename` in the code posted, you are only using `%2` in the subroutine - and that will include the extension (which is `.csv` in any case) and you are skipping over the `for /r %F...` (which wouldn't work since you need to double the `%` in batch for metavariables.) You appear to be prefixing each line in the body of your `.csv` files with `objects...%date%` but where you want to "add filename.ext" and what you mean by "filename.ext" you haven't said...

Comment: Thanks and Sorry for the confusion. I modified the original script. All I need is for the %filename% variable that was defined with ~nxf to show its Full content, It only posts filename without extension...

Comment: If makes more sense, I would only need a batch to add the output of  "  for /r %F in (*.pdf) do @echo %~nxF > %filename% "  into the first column of a already existing csv file. The above batch works, but I have to manually add ".pdf" into the code...

Comment: @CharlesCarminati It looks like you are using the file/folder name modifiers like `~nx` without knowing what they mean. Open a command prompt window and run `call /?` to get them explained in output help pages. And they are explained also in help of command __FOR__ output on running `for /?`.  The first help page for command __FOR__ explains also that in a batch file `%%variable` must be used instead of just `%variable` as in command prompt window. So you need `for /r %%F in (*.pdf) do @echo %%~nxF>"%filename%"` whereby I can't see where environment variable `filename` is defined at all.

Comment: @CharlesCarminati If you put a space character between `%%~nxF` and redirection operator `>` this space character is also written as trailing space into the file. I think, you don't want each file name with a trailing space in the text file, aren't you.